# Where is the code of load balancer used in cfs scheduler located?

Tags: linux, scheduler

I am not getting the code for load balancer used in  cfs scheduler whose code is  [(cfs sheduler's code is here)](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/sched/fair.c). Can someone please guide me for the same?

Answer (score 0):

It's in that code, check around line 7600, functions like:

- `fix_small_imbalance`
- `calculate_imbalance`
- `find_busiest_group`